# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger : addAppender

Tags: java, log4j

I'm working in migration project to migrate java version from `1.4` to `1.8`.
I succeed to upgrade the `jdk` and run the application into  `glassfich` server but I had always the problem of `log4j 1.1.3` and I had this error in `addAppender` method despite it's exists in the package of `log4j`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger (addAppender)
```

I tried to upgrade the log4j version and exclude `group org.slf4j` but the problem persists.

Below is my code :

build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
 compile group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.+'
 compile group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.4.0'
 compile group: 'xmlconvert', name: 'xflat', version: '2.2'
 compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.2'
 compile group: 'struts', name: 'struts', version: '1.1'
 compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.3'
 compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.1.3' }

 configurations.all{
   exclude group:"org.slf4j" , module: "log4j-over-slf4j"
  }
```

ApplicationListener.java

```
Category cat = Category.getInstance (sCat);
cat.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(LOG_PATTERN), logFile, true));
```

Do you have guys another propositions to resolve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, by default Glassfish does not provide Log4J support, so you should put the `log4j` jar inside the lib folder of Glassfish (`glassfish/lib/`).
Below the link of the solution :
https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/wiki-archive/FaqCongifureLog4J.html